# How to position this text in container in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm re-writing my application written in Kotlin to Flutter, but I'm struggling with simple layout.

I'm trying to re-create layout from Gmail, but I don't know how to position some things.

This is an image from the Kotlin app:
[image: Kotlin]

This is an image from my Flutter app:
[image: Flutter]

I'm talking about the "odebrane" text. I want it to be exactly like in my Kotlin app. I want the text inside it to be centered and I want it to be on the exact height to the "Voucher" text. Is there anyone who can help me?

Code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class GeneratedMailCouponScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String couponImage;

  GeneratedMailCouponScreen({Key key, @required this.couponImage}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_back
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.archive
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.delete
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.mail
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.more_vert
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16.0),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text('Voucher', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20.0)),
                  SizedBox(width: 16.0,),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.grey[300],
                    width: 50.0,
                    height: 8.0,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('Odebrane', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 8.0),),
                    )
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Change **Center** tag to **Padding** with padding value is 2 or 4

Comment: Have you tried `FitterBox` to center this text in Container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After test on device, this is my solution
You only need to change few line of code

```dart
// from
Container(
  color: Colors.grey[300],
  width: 50.0,
  height: 8.0,
  child: Center(
    child: Text('Odebrane', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 8.0),),
     )
   )

// to
Container(
      color: Colors.grey[300],
      child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4, 2, 4, 2),
             child: Text('Odebrane', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 10.0),),
      )
   )
```

Comment: And how about the "Odebrane" text to be at the same height as "Voucher" text?

Comment: You can try to set it with X = 20-4*2 (20 is Voucher fontsize, 4*2 is padding top and bottom)

Comment: How do I do that? Can you help me with that?

Comment: Just set fontSize of Odebrane  Text to **12** (20-4*2). What's problem?